# C++ Program generating errors on UnitTests

Tags: c++

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int amount;
    double salesD1 = 0, salesD2 = 0, salesD3 = 0;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Dealership 1 Sales Amount : ";
        cin >> amount;
        salesD1 += amount;
        cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Dealership 2 Sales Amount : ";
        cin >> amount;
        salesD2 += amount;
        cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'Y' ||  ch == 'y');
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Dealership 3 Sales Amount : ";
        cin >> amount;
        salesD3 += amount;
        cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\n\nDealership 1 Total Sales : $" << salesD1;
    cout << "\nDealership 2 Total Sales : $" << salesD2;
    cout << "\nDealership 3 Total Sales : $" << salesD3;
    cout << "\nTotal Sales : $" << (salesD1 + salesD2 + salesD3);
}
```

[image]

I have ran this and changed it a million times but i cannot figure out what is wrong and i even talked to a tutor from my school for over an hour and still the two of us couldnt figure it out.Im kinda lost here about to pull my hair out.

Comment: Please provide your [mcve] containing input and desired output as text.

Comment: They never teach this in school: when you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. **Never add to code that doesn't work.** That way, when you make a mistake, the program fails at once and you know where the bug is.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the amount as int but it's a floating point value.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        double amount;
        double salesD1 = 0, salesD2 = 0, salesD3 = 0;
        char ch;
        do
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Dealership 1 Sales Amount : ";
            cin >> amount;
            salesD1 += amount;
            cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
            cin >> ch;
        } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
        do
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Dealership 2 Sales Amount : ";
            cin >> amount;
            salesD2 += amount;
            cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
            cin >> ch;
        } while (ch == 'Y' ||  ch == 'y');
        do
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Dealership 3 Sales Amount : ";
            cin >> amount;
            salesD3 += amount;
            cout << "\nDo you want to enter more (y/n) : ";
            cin >> ch;
        } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\n\nDealership 1 Total Sales : $" << salesD1;
        cout << "\nDealership 2 Total Sales : $" << salesD2;
        cout << "\nDealership 3 Total Sales : $" << salesD3;
        cout << "\nTotal Sales : $" << (salesD1 + salesD2 + salesD3);
}
```

After I fixed it the output is

```
Dealership 1 Total Sales : $980.10
Dealership 2 Total Sales : $2325.43
Dealership 3 Total Sales : $4086.44
Total Sales : $7391.97
```

for input

```
980.1n2325.43n1194.64y2311.28y580.52n
```

As expected in the first test case